# Couldn't Connect to Docker Daemon on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using the newest version of Docker as of August 25, 2017, I know that Docker no longer requires a VirtualBox setup along with boot2docker to work. However, in trying to connect to it and use docker-compose, I am unable to connect to docker. My compose file works as when I install all necessary prerequisites using homebrew (and therefore use docker-machine), everything is fine. The error message is as follows:

```
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to start Docker for Mac.
```

I have since done the following to no avail:

- remove ~/.docker folder
- restart docker through the app
- restart the docker app itself
- open a new terminal session

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had some old docker environment variables in my `~/.bash_profile` that `docker-compose` was reading and trying to connect to `docker-machine`, as a result. After commenting out the following from my `~/.bash_profile`:

`export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/williamrwatson/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376`

I was good to go:

`Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_redis_1 ...
Creating docker_redis_1 ... done`